# Trouble finding button

Tags: python, selenium

I am having trouble with selenium not wanting to find a button. The code I used worked on previous buttons on the same website, but for some reason it is having trouble finding this one.

Here is the HTML:

```
<button id="getCoupon" class="getCoupon" onclick="IWant()" style="" data-i18n="view_prod_get_coupon">Get Your Coupon</button>
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('getCoupon').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="getCoupon"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name('getCoupon').click()
```

Here are the errors for the last two:
Trying with XPath:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="getCoupon"]"}
```

Trying with class name:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"getCoupon"}
```

Comment: Try to add scroll to the buttom, if you are doing it onwebsite like aliexpress, it doesnt work until you scroll down, give it a try and you will see :) let me know if it helped

Comment: Sorry I am all new to this. How would you scroll to the very bottom?

Comment: I tried 
    web_element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
    web_element.send_keys(Keys.END)
 but that did not scroll. There were no error messages, but is also did not scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Your locator seems fine, Probably execution happening and fast as your element not getting load on time. You can try using explicit waits

```
// wait for element present 

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "getCoupon"))
element.click()

// wait until element get visible

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "getCoupon"))
element.click()
```

For debugging purpose you can also use a method like

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('getCoupon')

if element.is_displayed():
    element.click()
else:
    print ("element not visible ")
```

don't forget to import required packages. Refer [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for more.

Comment: good answer! I will suggest using `element_to_be_clickable` instead of `presence_of_element_located` or `visibility_of_element_located` sence he is trying to click on it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into html code. I think it can be:

1. This button may be in frame then you need to switch to frame first and then to locate button.
2. Maybe it javascript generated, so you need to wait until it will be generated by js code.

Comment: There are no <frame> tags at all.
I have also tried to let it sleep to see if your second suggestion would work but I got the same error.